# Как проверить двойное нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствутйе!

Вот этот код проверяет, если пользователь нажал `Enter`

```
$('#text').keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {        
                    alert('ВЫ НАЖАЛИ  ENTER');
      }
    });
```

А как написать условие, которое срабатывает, если пользователь два раза подряд нажал `Enter`? (а когда один раз - то другое условие?)

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение [How to trap double key press in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223764/how-to-trap-double-key-press-in-javascript).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!